# Desktop Icons Missing in Unity, New 17.10 Upgrade

Tags: unity, upgrade, icons, 17.10

Finished the upgrade last night, logged into a black desktop.  The launch bar and top bar is there and working, and everything else in the system works as normal.

I was able to specify a wallpaper file in settings and it displays, but still no icons, no action if I right-click on the desktop.  There's just nothing there.

Any ideas of things to try?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you in Unity or in GNOME? Unity is no longer supported and was replaced by GNOME in 17.10. Please post a screenshot. I think under GNOME there are no icons on the background any more.

Comment: Added https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BfeH.png screenshot.

Comment: Huh, that's Unity. How weird. What version did you upgrade from?

Comment: This was upgraded from 17.04.  I selected "Unity" from the login options.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Gnome install **gnome-tweak-tool** and make sure that *Show Icons* is set under *Desktop*.[image]

If you are still using Unity, you can use the Terminal to do this:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.background show-desktop-icons true`

Comment: Hi, that tool is shown in the original screenshot, those settings are already in place.

Comment: Hey. Didn't see that screenshot before. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update, yes, these settings are one of the first things I tried.  The desktop is nothing, there's no response, no right-click, nothing.  Still no icons.

Comment: @DFarmerTX Have you tried opening nautilus? If the icons don't display then, you seem to be experiencing a bug.

Comment: Hi, nautilus works fine, I can open my desktop folder and see my launcher icons.  There's just nothing where the desktop is supposed to be.  I'll dig though the syslog and see what its saying.

Comment: synaptic package manager can do it in a gui, i.e.  search package, highlight package > menu item  Package > click on "Automatically Installed" to remove check mark (if not checked then it's already manually installed. Or read here to use apt-mark command - http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-mark.8.html So that's `sudo apt-mark manual packagename` replacing packagename with actual package to be set to manual.